# change the headers of GridView, bind to a dictionary

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, dictionary

I have a GridView that is bound to a Dictionary object that i created.

This is the result:

[image]

How do i change the headers (Key,Value)?

Thanks,

liron

P.S This is for homework so i have no choice but to add the data dynamically by code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said this is homework, I am hesitant to give exact code, but I will say:

The RowCreated event of a GridView is fired **for each row** of the GridView, including the header.  You can then determine the RowType of the row being created and set the text of each cell.

Comment: This is my Code:  SqlDataReader dr = dbS.executeCommand(SELECT_COMMAND_ORDER_BY_DATE);//Select command
            Dictionary<string, double> Market_value = new  Dictionary<string, double>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Market_value.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["Date"]),                                  Convert.ToDouble(dr["Market Value"]));
            }
           
                      
            tMarketVGv.DataSource = Market_value;
            tMarketVGv.DataBind();                                             so where can i change or determine the RowType?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are filling a dictionary with data instead of just binding the tMarketVGv directly to the DataReader?

Comment: Yes, because i got this error: "The data source does not support server-side data paging", and because it was a part of the homework instructions. Do you know how can i change the headers (working with sqlDataReader)?